# Basic Python - finding difference between elements in a list - IndexError

Tags: python, python-3.x, index-error

I'm trying to find the daily increase in a bank account for 5 days. I have a list created. I need to create a new list tracking those daily increases so that later on I can find an average increase, max increase, etc. The problem I'm having is I keep getting an Indexerror.  Can anyone please help me? I'm getting very frustrated. I've done similar coding before (without determining difference between 2 elements) and I have no problem. The moment I add math to the module, it blows up.

Code is below (the reason I have all the print statements is a double-check to make sure the lists are correct):

```
acct_balance = [9852.24,9854.25,9954.24,9985.56,10056.98]

index = 0
total = 0
amt_increase = []
while index < len(acct_balance):
    if index != 0:
        change = acct_balance[index+1] - acct_balance[index]
        amt_increase.append(change)
        total = total + change
    index = index + 1

print('Account balances: ',acct_balance)
print('Daily Increase: ',amt_increase)
print('Total Increases: ',total)
```

I then get the below error when I try to run it:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Rogue\Desktop\Rogue Help\HELP.py", line 9, in <module>
    change = acct_balance[index+1] - acct_balance[index]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

This is for school, so I can't use coding I've never seen before, and therefore don't understand.  Thank you!

Comment: index starts at zero. Your condition in the while is while index < len(acct_balance). When you reach the last one, you sum +1, and you get out of index.

Comment: Wow.  Thank you EVERYONE for your help! I'm really enjoying Python, but this was frustrating.  I read everyone's answers, and it eventually just clicked!  I'm not using anyone's exact ideas, only because I have to write my code the way my brain works (I hope you understand).  So I left my coding the same EXCEPT I changed my math to read:      change = acct_balance[index] - acct_balance[index-1].  It worked!  I actually started clapping my hands because I'm so excited.  I can't thank you all enough. You are the best!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
acct_balance = [9852.24,9854.25,9954.24,9985.56,10056.98]
acct_increase = []

for index, value in enumerate(acct_balance):
    if index == 0:
        continue
    acct_increase.append(acct_balance[index] - acct_balance[index - 1])
```

They say there are two hard things in computer science: naming conventions, cache misses, and off-by-one errors.

Instead of looking forward in the array (which is causing you to look over the end), always look backwards after skipping the 0th element. Also dont use while loops for looping over arrays in python, always use for-each loops. Do I get your homework credit :)

Answer (score 2):

Your loop is checking your list for an element that doesn't exist.
The length of your loop is five. So if you increment your index by one every iteration of the loop, you will eventually end up referencing an element [element 6] that doesn't exist in your list and python will throw an error saying "list index out of range"

If you see a "list index out of range" error again, I would check to make sure you didn't accidentally write your code to reference past the bounds of a list.

Answer (score 0):

You're making your loop too complicated, which makes it hard to think about how the indices work. Replacing it with a `for` loop should help clear up the logic:

```
amt_increase = []
for index in range(1, len(acct_balance)):
    change = acct_balance[index] - acct_balance[index - 1]
    amt_increase.append(change)
    total += change
```

The problem in your original was that on the last step, you tried to access the next index, which doesn't exist. I've inverted that so that it checks the previous day instead, so that the limits of the `range` are easy to read.

If you want to go a step farther and feel comfortable with list comprehensions, you can turn the loop into a single expression (excepting calculating `total`, but you could do that later in a variety of ways):

```
amt_increase = [today - yesterday
                for today, yesterday
                in zip(acct_balance[1:], acct_balance[:-1])]
```

Zipping the sliced lists lets you line them up the right way.